# Using Selenium to determine the visibility of elements for Print media

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver

I would like to determine if particular elements on a page are visible when printed as controlled by CSS `@media` rules.

Is there a way to do this with Selenium?

I know there is the [isDisplayed](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/default/webdriver-spec.html#determining-if-an-element-is-displayed) method, which takes the CSS into account, but there is nothing I can find to tell Selenium which media type to apply.

Is there a way to do this?

Or is there another way to test web pages to make sure the elements you want are printed (and those you don't aren't)?

Update:

For clarity, there are no plans to have a javascript print button. The users will print using the normal print functionality of the browser (Chrome, FF and IE). `@media` css rules will be used to control what is shown and hidden. **I would like Selenium to pretend it is a printer instead of a screen, so I can test if certain elements will be visible in what would be the printed version of the page.**

Comment: I've looked around, but unfortunately nobody is doing what you're trying to accomplish. I even looked at the source code of the popular Web Developer extension, but it only works when the media type is specified on a `<link type="stylesheet" rel="print"` tag and not when it's specified inside the CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've managed to write a script that does just what you want: it hides screen-only styles and sets print-only styles to be screen-only.

You need to inject the following JavaScript with Selenium:

```
(function pretendToBeAPrinter() {
    //For looking up if something is in the media list
    function hasMedia(list, media) {
        if (!list) return false;

        var i = list.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (list[i] === media) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Loop though all stylesheets
    for (var styleSheetNo = 0; styleSheetNo < document.styleSheets.length; styleSheetNo++) {
        //Current stylesheet
        var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[styleSheetNo];

        //Output debug information
        console.info("Stylesheet #" + styleSheetNo + ":");
        console.log(styleSheet);

        //First, check if any media queries have been defined on the <style> / <link> tag

        //Disable screen-only sheets
        if (hasMedia(styleSheet.media, "screen") && !hasMedia(styleSheet.media, "print")) {
            styleSheet.disabled = true;
        }

        //Display "print" stylesheets
        if (!hasMedia(styleSheet.media, "screen") && hasMedia(styleSheet.media, "print")) {
            //Add "screen" media to show on screen
            styleSheet.media.appendMedium("screen");
        }

        // Get the CSS rules in a cross-browser compatible way
        var rules;
        try {
            rules = styleSheet.cssRules;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        try {
          rules = styleSheet.rules;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }

        // Handle cases where styleSheet.rules is null
        if (!rules) {
            continue;
        }

        //Second, loop through all the rules in a stylesheet
        for (var ruleNo = 0; ruleNo < rules.length; ruleNo++) {
            //Current rule
            var rule = rules[ruleNo];

            //Hide screen-only rules
            if (hasMedia(rule.media, "screen") && !hasMedia(rule.media, "print")) {
                //Rule.disabled doesn't work here, so we remove the "screen" rule and add the "print" rule so it isn't shown
                console.info('Rule.media:');
                console.log(rule.media)
                rule.media.appendMedium(':not(screen)');
                rule.media.deleteMedium('screen');
                console.info('Rule.media after tampering:');
                console.log(rule.media)
            }

            //Display "print" rules
            if (!hasMedia(rule.media, "screen") && hasMedia(rule.media, "print")) {
                //Add "screen" media to show on screen
                rule.media.appendMedium("screen");
            }
        }
    }
})()
```

You can [see it in action at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4JA4/14/).

## Bookmarklet

You can also [install it as a bookmarklet](http://jsbin.com/qihenego/3/).

## More information:

- [About `mediaList`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljcgwmel.php)
- [About `document.styleSheets`](http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets)

**Note:** I've only tested this in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. It may or may not work in other browsers.

Comment: clever. Very clever. I love it. Thank you!

Comment: @TomHoward I've updated the script so it works in Mozilla Firefox as well (and probably other browsers, too).

Comment: I ran into trouble in Chrome v64 with a DomException so I've updated accessing the cssRules to handle it. Someone with more JS knowledge might know a better fix

Comment: This is awesome. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There is some cases that it can be useful to use visual automation tools such as [applitools](http://applitools.com/).
We implements it in some of our tests, and it's great so far.

Comment: I could find any reference to print media in it's docs. Can you?

Comment: Not specifically to print, but it helps us to analyze visual components.

Answer (score -1):

```
      //jquery

     function printDetail() {
         window.print();
     }
     //html
      <button type="button" class="btn" value="Print Div" onclick="printDetail()"><i class="icon-print"></i> &nbsp;Print</button>

      //css
      @media print{
          .header{display:none;}
          .footer{display:none;}
          .leftside{display:none;}
          .rightside{display:block;}

     }

  // http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/52H7g/
```

Comment: Yep, so how do I use selenium (or some other tool) to check that the header is not displayed when printed?

Comment: yes, my friend, whitin @media print use display:none and display:block; so <header></header> use css media print{header{display:none;}} and another use display:none and display:block;

Comment: Umm, no that's how you implement it. This question about how to test this. i.e. if someone changes it to `@media print{header{display:none;}}` I want a test on the CI server to fail, so someone can go and fix it.

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. I already know how to use `@media` rules. What I don't have is an automated test that can confirm if certain content on the page is visible when printed. For instance, just say a developer on my team changes the page or the CSS so a specific table is no longer visible. In those situations, I would like the test to fail. More importantly, we are using TDD and I don't even know where to start with this test.

Answer (score -1):

I think I have a little clever way to accomplish this:

1. Can I assume that the PRINT button is going to be on the html page as is the case in the jsfiddle.net link above?
2. Basically, can I EXCLUDE the FILE->PRINT or RIGHT CLICK->PRINT options and only assume that the only way someone can print your page is by clicking on a print button embedded in your html page as shown in the jsfiddle link above if not what are other test cases?
3. Finally, can I assume that your selenium tests will ONLY run in the Chrome browser and not firefox? This is important because the PRINT command behaves different in Chrome as it does in Firefox. My fix will only work w/ Chrome.

Comment: There are no plans to have a print button. The users will print using the normal print functionality of the browser (Chrome, FF and IE). `@media` css rules will be used to control what is shown and hidden. I would like Selenium to pretend it is a printer instead of a screen, so I can test if certain elements will be visible in the printed version on the page.